# subprocess.Popen completion kills the main script

Tags: python, popen

My script needs to install a couple of packages from the system repositories so I do:

```
def install_dependencies(env):
   from_manager, from_source = parse_config(env)
   cmd = ["sudo", "apt-get", "install", "-y"].extend(from_manager)
   manager_output = subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()
   return manager_output
```

Thing is this install the packages correctly but exits the script after the call so it never returns `manager_output`.

I'm sure it doesn't have to do with the subprocess error code. But I wonder how to avoid it exiting my script.

Comment: ``subprocess.Popen`` shouldn't terminate the parent process (*your Python application*). Are you sure something isn't **killing** your app?

Comment: No, not sure. But what would kill my script in this context? there is nothing else running. I can put a breakpoint before the `return` but it doesn't get there.

Comment: Check your system logs in ``/var/log`` -- Maybe something is killing it?

Comment: You mean /var/log/syslog? anyway, there's nothing interesting in the logs. I'm calling apt-get with no more than 10 packages. What should I look for first? What could be killing the process halfway?

Comment: I would check ``kernel.log`` and/or ``dmesg``. Other than that I dont' know sorry :/ I can't think of a reason why the process should kill the parent and not return from your function.